# Splitting a string into one value

Tags: java, regex, string

I have string of below format.

> {"id":"1tr0vm","title":"Professional business consultant in
>   Cookeville, TN at IAG","category":"business"}

i would like to split it as

> {"id":"1tr0vm "title":"Professional business consultant in
>   Cookeville, TN at IAG" "category":"business"}

currently i am doing it this way string.split(",")
but this is not working if there is ',' any where else in the string.
i the above case

> "Professional business consultant in Cookeville, TN at IAG"

is split into two, but need it as a whole string.

Comment: That's not a string, that **JSON** and to get the values from it, you should use the functions provided by Java.

Comment: i know that's a json. I am reading it from file as a string and want to process it as string.

Comment: To Tushar's point: rather than using a regex (`string.split(...)`), you should use a fully JSON parser.

Comment: You can use a JSON parser/library, eg. GSON.

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Try `string.split("(?<=\"),")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, what i understand is that, you want to create a JSON object from a string. Try as below:

UPDATE:

Try and download the gson library from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson231jar.htm and add to your libs folder and add to build path.

Then code like this

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

class JsonCheck{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Details details = null;
        String json = "{\"id\":\"1tr0vm\",\"title\":\"Professional business consultant in Cookeville, TN at IAG\",\"category\":\"business\"}";
        Gson gsoObj = new Gson();
        details = gsoObj.fromJson(json, Details.class);
        System.out.println(details.id);
    }

    private class Details {
        private String id = "";
        private String title = "";
        private String category = "";
    }
}
```

Modify it like your requirements

Comment: please can you include the complete code with the jar file used.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. And you dont need to use any new jar files for this. Only do the imports as shown in the answer

Comment: I am getting error check this http://pastie.org/10728415 for the code. I am using java.json.jar.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a String it's a Json . if you want to convert it into a String this is how you do it

As you reading the file as a String you can convert it into Json Object and then extract the data

```
   JsonObject obj = new JsonObject("String extracted ");

String id = obj.getString("id");

String title = JsonObject.getString("title");
```

This is how you do it . I hope this was helpful , ThankYou

Comment: Which jar file are you using.